# Inject a repository which has Generic as well as Concrete Implementation to a controller

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, .net-core, repository

I am making a generic repository but for some entities I also need functionalities not provided by the generic repository. I have an interface IGenericRepository and concrete implementation as GenericRepository with basic CRUD operations. Further I have a studentRepository that uses the generic repository but also has functionalities of its own independent from the Generic Repository for which i have an Interface called IStudentRepository.

Here is the sample code:

```
  public interface IGenericEntityRepository<T> 
  {
        Delete(T entity);

        T Get(int id);

        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

        Add(T entity);

        Update(T entity);
  }


public class GenericEntityRepository<T> : IGenericEntityRepository<T> where T : class
 {

        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

        public GenericEntityRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            this._applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        }

     //Generic Repository Implementations....
 }


 public interface IStudentRepository
 {
      string GetFullName(Student student)
      double GetGpa(Student student)
 }

 public class StudentRepository: GenericRepository<Student>, IStudentRepository
 {
    public StudentRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) : base(applicationDbContext)
    {}

    //IStudentRepository functions' implementations...
 }

Now I need to inject this StudentRepository to my StudentsController 

 public class StudentsController : Controller
 {
        private readonly IGenericEntityRepository<Student> _genericStudentRepository;

        public StudentsController(IGenericEntityRepository<Student> _genericStudentRepository)
        {
            this._genericStudentRepository = genericRepository;           
        }

        public void testAccessibility() 
        {
             this._genericStudentRepository.GetAll() //valid call
             this._genericStudentRepository.GetAllGpa() //invalid Call 
             ***As expected cause IGenericEntityRepository doesn't have that ***function 
        }  

 }
```

As you can see the probelem here, if I inject IGenericEntityRepository I only get the genericrepository functionalities. If i want the functionalities of Student repository not included in genericRepository I have to inject both IGenericEntityRepository and IStudentRepository like below and vice versa.

```
 public class StudentsController : Controller
 {
        private readonly IGenericEntityRepository<Student> _genericStudentRepository;
        private readonly IStudentRepository _studentsRepository;

        public StudentsController(IGenericEntityRepository<Student> _genericStudentRepository, IStudentRepository studentsRepository)
        {
            this._genericStudentRepository = genericRepository;
            this.__studentsRepository = studentsRepository;
        }

  public void testAccessibility() 
        {
             this._genericStudentRepository.GetAll() //valid call
             this._studentsRepository.GetAllGpa() //valid call 
        }  



 }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Doesn't feel right injecting two contextually same but coding wise different objects like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `IStudentRepository` extend `IGenericEntityRepository<T>`:

```
public interface IStudentRepository : IGenericEntityRepository<Student> 
{
      string GetFullName(Student student)
      double GetGpa(Student student)
}
```

Now injecting `IStudentRepository` should be enough to use all the functions.

Comment: Would work but then the Generic repository I have, and its basic CRUD functions I have already written, will be duplicated everywhere in concrete repositories.

Comment: @PrajwolCE No it wouldn't be duplicated. You are already inheriting from GenericRepository<Student>, that means you already implement the methods on the generic interface. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Yup you are correct, I was extending the Concrete StudeRepository all the time and baffled why it wasn't working when I should have been extending its Inferface! :) Thank you very very much, been pulling my hair since morning!